# Unzip a string on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, unzip

I'm looking for a way to unzip a string on Windows Phone. Found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343465/compression-decompression-string-with-c-sharp), but the GZipStream class is not available on WP. Could you please recommend me something to look at?

**UPD.:** [Here is the solution using SharpZipLib](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/5909/16946.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SharpGIS's really small Zip utility](http://www.sharpgis.net/2010/08/default.aspx). I've never used it but it might work for you.

Comment: Works on streams doesnt it? in which case you could write your string to a stream (using StreamWriter) and unzip on that.

Answer (score 0):

DotNetZip seems to have a Silverlight port, (which contains GZipStream.cs)

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/releases/view/68268

You can check if it can help you decompress the string.