# compression and utf8 encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

can someone tell me why I'm loosing information doing this process ? Some utf8 chars appears not decoded :
`"Biography":"\u003clink type=...` or `Steve Blunt \u0026 Marty Kelley`
but others do : `"Name":"朱敬`

```
// Creating a 64bit string containing gzip data
string bar;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(gzip, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write(s);
    }
    ms.Flush();
    bar = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}

// Reading it
string foo;
byte[] itemData = Convert.FromBase64String(bar);
using (MemoryStream src = new MemoryStream(itemData))
using (GZipStream gzs = new GZipStream(src, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (MemoryStream dest = new MemoryStream(itemData.Length*2))
{
    gzs.CopyTo(dest);
    foo = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dest.ToArray());
}

Console.WriteLine(foo);
```

Comment: There's a semicolon after your first `using` statement that probably doesn't belong there.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with your code, it works fine for me. Are you sure the characters aren't already encoded in the source string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be because you are writing the string using `StreamWriter` but reading it using `CopyTo()` and `Encoding.GetString()`.

What happens if you try this?

```
// Reading it
string foo;
byte[] itemData = Convert.FromBase64String(bar);
using (MemoryStream src = new MemoryStream(itemData))
using (GZipStream gzs = new GZipStream(src, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(gzs, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    foo = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Although I think you should be using `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`:

```
string s = "Biography:\u003clink type...";
string bar;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(gzip, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write(s);
    }
    ms.Flush();
    bar = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}

// Reading it
string foo;
byte[] itemData = Convert.FromBase64String(bar);
using (MemoryStream src = new MemoryStream(itemData))
using (GZipStream gzs = new GZipStream(src, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(gzs, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    foo = reader.ReadString();
}

Console.WriteLine(foo);
```

Comment: reader.ReadString --> "the string is prefixed with the length" (at least in VB.NET) Totally messes up my Decompress since I wasn't using BinaryWriter

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Indeed that would mess it up. That's why my example above is careful to use BinaryWriter with BinaryReader.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was simply that the characters were already encoded in the source string.

*Ps : Credit goes to [rik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5409/rik) for this answer :)*

*Edit : I also had the StreamReader issue [matthew-watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson) was suggesting.*