# How to compress or compact a string in Python

Tags: python, string, compression, stream-compaction

I'm making a python "script" that sends a string to a webservice (in C#). I NEED to compress or compact this string, because the bandwidth and MBs data is LIMITED (yeah, in capitals because it's very limited).

I was thinking of converting it into a file and then compressing the file. But I'm looking for a method to directly compress the string.

How can I compress or compact the string?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/archiving.html

Comment: Will your web service understand your compressed string?

Comment: @Selcuk That's the idea. My webservice will descompress the string and store it in a database. If is important, the web service is in C# (.NET)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

How about [zlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html)?

```py
import zlib

a = "this string needs compressing"
a = zlib.compress(a.encode())
print(zlib.decompress(a).decode())  # outputs original contents of a
```

You can also use `sys.getsizeof(obj)` to see how much data an object takes up before and after compression.

Comment: Is there zlib avalaible in other lenguages? My web service is in C# (Sorry for not adding that information).

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343465/compression-decompression-string-with-c-sharp)

Comment: In Python 3 `zlib.compress()` takes a bytes-like value, so you need to do something like `zlib.compress(a.encode())` for it to work.

Answer (score 13):

```
import sys
import zlib


text=b"""This function is the primary interface to this module along with 
decompress() function. This function returns byte object by compressing the data 
given to it as parameter. The function has another parameter called level which 
controls the extent of compression. It an integer between 0 to 9. Lowest value 0 
stands for no compression and 9 stands for best compression. Higher the level of 
compression, greater the length of compressed byte object."""

# Checking size of text
text_size=sys.getsizeof(text)
print("\nsize of original text",text_size)

# Compressing text
compressed = zlib.compress(text)

# Checking size of text after compression
csize=sys.getsizeof(compressed)
print("\nsize of compressed text",csize)

# Decompressing text
decompressed=zlib.decompress(compressed)

#Checking size of text after decompression
dsize=sys.getsizeof(decompressed)
print("\nsize of decompressed text",dsize)

print("\nDifference of size= ", text_size-csize)
```

[image]

Comment: In Python 3, If you change `text` to a string, `compressed = zlib.compress(text)` should be `compressed = zlib.compress(text.encode())`. It seems that this is most effective with longer strings. I tried this with a 43-long `[a-v]` string, and the size difference (SD) was only 10. Using `brotlipy`, the SD was 23.