# Passing large strings in .Net Remoting

Tags: c#, .net, compression, remoting, .net-remoting

I have a .Net Remoting service that will return a class to the client application. That class has a string property where the string can range from 1kb to 400kb worth of data.

I tried passing 256kb worth of string from server to client and the client was able to get it in less than 5 seconds which is still ok since this call will only be used for trouble-shooting purposes by an administrator. However I read
[here](https://petabridge.com/blog/large-messages-and-sockets-in-akkadotnet/) that when sending huge data: "the socket will be blocked from receiving all other messages until it receives the remaining .... packets". If my data ever reached an MB size **I do not want to block the client from receiving other messages.**

How can I achieve my goal of not blocking the client? Do I compress the string using GZipStream like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343465/compression-decompression-string-with-c-sharp)? Or are there other better ways?

Answer (score 0):

Good article from Tess Fernandez : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2008/09/02/outofmemoryexceptions-while-remoting-very-large-datasets/