# Base64 to ZIP Base64 without writing to disk

Tags: c#, zip, base64

As the title says, is the following process possible **without writing to disk** in C#?

- Decode a Base64 string
- Zip the decoded file
- Create a Base64 string of the zipped file.

So for example, if my input is  `1ab2c3d4e5` which is the base64 encode of a picture, I'd like my output to be `4d89x7g4d4` which is the base64 encode of the ZIP containing the picture.

I have found examples of how to create a ZIP file from a `Byte[]` array, but these always save the resulted ZIP file on disk, and in my scenario: **nothing should be written to disk EVER**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  (see my answer) [Compression/Decompression string with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17993002/1315444)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I guess I should have looked for 'Compression' instead of just 'ZIP'. Thank you!