# AWS SNS metadata when pushing to SQS

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm using .net sdk to push messages to SNS which then publishes messages to subscribed SQS Queues, but SNS adds metadata such as message type etc, and i end up with larger JSON payload which i do not want, especially when SQS is limited to 256k per message.

Is it possible to send a command to SNS and tell it not to send that metadata?

Here's the code:

```
var credentials = new StoredProfileAWSCredentials("dev");

using (var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
{
    var request = new PublishRequest();
    request.Message = message;
    request.TargetArn = "ARN";

    var response = client.Publish(request);
    // return response;
}
```

This is what SNS pushes to SQS:

```
{  
   "Type":"Notification",
   "MessageId":"3333333",
   "TopicArn":"ARN",
   "Message": {
       "Id":45,
       "MessageId":"a871f8d7-7091-4548-87c5-da3bb4131044",
       "Payload": {
           "Internalid":"a7c50558-fc9c-47a6-b0ed-cb0cf5020f55",
           "MessageId":"a871f8d7-7091-4548-87c5-da3bb4131044",
           "TravelersName":"aaa aaaa",
           "TravelersEmail":"aaa@aa.com",
           "OwnersEmail":null,
           "AccommodationId":1,
           "BookingCode":"a523cd07-5506-48ad-9380-2e94002722e0"
       },
       "EventName":"BookingRecordCreated",
       "CreatedOnUtc":"2016-09-26T15:14:55.437",
       "HandledOnUtc":null
    },
    "Timestamp":"2016-09-26T15:14:50.923Z",
    "SignatureVersion":"1",
    "Signature":"dfgdfg///==",
    "SigningCertURL":"https://sns",
    "UnsubscribeURL":"https://sns."
}
```

and this is what i publish to SNS

```
"Message":{
   "Id":45,
   "MessageId":"a871f8d7-7091-4548-87c5-da3bb4131044",
   "Payload": {
       "Internalid":"a7c50558-fc9c-47a6-b0ed-cb0cf5020f55",
       "MessageId":"a871f8d7-7091-4548-87c5-da3bb4131044",
       "TravelersName":"aa aaa",
       "TravelersEmail":"aa@aaa.com",
       "OwnersEmail":null,
       "AccommodationId":1,
       "BookingCode":"a523cd07-5506-48ad-9380-2e94002722e0",
       "EventName":"BookingRecordCreated",
       "CreatedOnUtc":"2016-09-26T15:14:55.437",
       "HandledOnUtc":null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to enable RAW Message delivery in SNS:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/large-payload-raw-message.html

> In addition to sending large payloads, with Amazon SNS you can now
>   enable raw message delivery for messages delivered to either Amazon
>   SQS endpoints or HTTP/S endpoints. This eliminates the need for the
>   endpoints to process JSON formatting, which is created for the Amazon
>   SNS metadata when raw message delivery is not selected. For example
>   ***when enabling raw message delivery for an Amazon SQS endpoint, the
>   Amazon SNS metadata is not included and the published message is
>   delivered to the subscribed Amazon SQS endpoint as is.***

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you compress the data before you publish to sns. By which you can send large amount of data. I am sure you should be able to find many codes to compress your data.

This is what I used before.
[Compression/Decompression string with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343465/compression-decompression-string-with-c-sharp)