# Modify site content and render it in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, proxy, compression

I am writing a proxy for some site using ASP.NET Core 2.0. My proxy works fine if all it does is just re-translating `HttpResponseMessage` to the browser. My proxy based on [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy) example. But I need to make some changes site content, for instance, some of the href contains an absolute reference. So when I click them from my proxy, I get to the original site, and it is a problem.

When I tried to get site HTML as a string, I got only special characters. After some search, I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343465/compression-decompression-string-with-c-sharp) solution. It fits for my case well and I successfully get site content as a string, which starts with `"<!DOCTYPE html>..."`. After changes are done I need to send this string to my browser, and here I have a problem. I work with the `HttpResponseMessage` the following way:

```
using (var responseStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
    string str;
    using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(gZipStream))
    {
        str = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        //some stings changes...
    }
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            await msi.CopyToAsync(gZipStream);
            await gZipStream.CopyToAsync(response.Body, StreamCopyBufferSize, context.RequestAborted);
        }
    }
    //next string works, but I don't change content this way
    //await responseStream.CopyToAsync(response.Body, StreamCopyBufferSize, context.RequestAborted);
}
```

I create `GZipStream`, successfully copy `MemoryStream` into it, then I want to copy `GZipStream` into a `response.Body` (`HttpResponse`) using `CopyToAsync`. On that line I get `NotSupportedException' with message

> GZipStream does not support reading

I find out, after compression into `GZipStream` `gZipStream.CanRead` is `false` for some reason. I tried to copy `msi` into `response.Body`, it doesn't throw exceptions, but in the browser, I get an empty page (document Response in Network in browser console is also empty).

Hope someone will be able to tell me, that I am doing wrong.