# Encode and Decode long string to short readable code

Tags: c#, base64, compression, encode

Suppose we have an object like:

```
public class Record
{
    public string ServerID {get;set;}
    public string UID {get;set;}
}
```

`ServerID` and `UID` are long string keys, I am trying to make that two parameters to short readable string maximum 8 characters for end-user, I can `Encode` and `Decode` by below snipped code.

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
{
    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
{
    var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

For example I have something like: 
`UID=1.2.840.113619.2.55.3.2831218035.988.1445761334.630&SystemID=BD99-370B-29C5-E424-5C61-0D70-E62B-5DDE`

but unfortunately by `Base64Encode` it will be:
 `VUlEPTEuMi44NDAuMTEzNjE5LjIuNTUuMy4yODMxMjE4MDM1Ljk4OC4xNDQ1NzYxMzM0LjYzMCZTeXN0ZW1JRD1CRDk5LTM3MEItMjlDNS1FNDI0LTVDNjEtMEQ3MC1FNjJCLTVEREU=`.

Is there a way to compress it something like `VUlEPTEu` and decode it to main version of string.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17993002/1350913) may help.

Comment: I have tried it before and the output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Decrypt data with `RijndaelManaged` class (System.Security.Cryptography) .
Some time ego i use this class and encrypted string was shorter than decrypted string.

Comment: This will give almost same result.