# How to fix 'Found invalid data while decoding.'

Tags: c#, compression, gzip

When I am trying to deflate one string to XML getting the error. can anyone help me out, if the string is wrong or any other thing I need to consider?

```
string output = DecompressString("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");

    public static string DecompressString(string compressedString)
    {
        byte[] decompressedBytes;

        var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(compressedString));

        using (var decompressorStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            using (var decompressedStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                decompressorStream.CopyTo(decompressedStream);

                decompressedBytes = decompressedStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedBytes);
    }
```

Comment: Catch the exception?

Comment: Already catched the exception in decompressorStream.CopyTo(decompressedStream); line.and the message is invalid data.need to find a way to avoid this.

Comment: Use valid data, or fix the data in the catch block.

Comment: need some help on fixing. can you guide me. as per client, this is valid data.

Comment: During decompress.

Comment: Do you have the option of using gzip and use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17993002/2137237 ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
public static string DecodeGzip(string str)
{
    byte[] gzBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(str);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(gzBuffer, 0);
        ms.Write(gzBuffer, 0, gzBuffer.Length);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[msgLength];

        ms.Position = 0;
        int length;
        using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            length = zip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        var data = new byte[length];
        Array.Copy(buffer, data, length);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some context here? Why did you choose a totally different stream type? What did you decide was wrong with your original code?

Comment: Not a Deflate algorithm :(