# How to read from either gzip or plain text reader in golang?

Tags: go, gzip

I'm writing a small webapp in golang, and it involves parsing a file uploaded by the user. I'd like to auto-detect if the file is gzipped or not and create readers / scanners appropriately. One twist is that I can't read the whole file into memory, I can only operate on the stream alone. Here's what I've got:

```
func scannerFromFile(reader io.Reader) (*bufio.Scanner, error) {

var scanner *bufio.Scanner
//create a bufio.Reader so we can 'peek' at the first few bytes
bReader := bufio.NewReader(reader)

testBytes, err := bReader.Peek(64) //read a few bytes without consuming
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
//Detect if the content is gzipped
contentType := http.DetectContentType(testBytes)

//If we detect gzip, then make a gzip reader, then wrap it in a scanner
if strings.Contains(contentType, "x-gzip") {
    gzipReader, err := gzip.NewReader(bReader)
    if (err != nil) {
        return nil, err
    }

    scanner = bufio.NewScanner(gzipReader)

} else {
    //Not gzipped, just make a scanner based on the reader
    scanner = bufio.NewScanner(bReader)
}

return scanner, nil
}
```

This works fine for plain text, but for gzipped data it inflates incorrectly, and after a few kb I inevitably get garbled text. Is there a simpler method out there? Any ideas why after a few thousand lines it uncompresses incorrectly?

Comment: Makes me wonder if something outside this code is faulty--garbled text from a gzip reader is definitely something I don't expect. (Edit: whoops, that "don't" is important. :) )

Comment: If the compressed stream itself were corrupted I'd expect you to get a CRC error; could be something before compression or after decompression--anyway, I fear there may not be enough information here to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

You can detect that a file is gziped by checking if the first 2 bytes are equal to `0x1f8b` (I found that information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059302/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-gzip-compressed)).

In comments someone mentioned that you should check these bytes separately, so the first one is `0x1f` and the second is `0x8b`.

```
testBytes, err := bReader.Peek(2) //read 2 bytes
....
if testBytes[0] == 31 && testBytes[1] == 139 {
    //gzip
}else{
   ...
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone - turns out that twotwotwo and thundercat were correct, and the stream was getting corrupted in a spot unrelated to the code I posted. Weirdly, it seems to be related to writing to the http response while still reading from the request stream. I'm still investigating it, but it seems the original question was misguided.