# Unzip string starting with 0x1f8b (gzip?)

Tags: r, compression, gzip

Having a string like:

```
txt <- "0x1f8b0800000000000000ed3cdb72db38b2eff315..."
```

How can i read the content as plain text? 
If i interpret [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6059302/3301344) question correctly that the string starts with `0x1f8b` means that it is gziped...

I tried writing it and then reading it via

```
tmp <- tempfile()
writeLines(txt, tmp)
readLines(gzfile(tmp))
```

But this just returned the same string...

Comment: Maybe write the binary represetation to a file and re-read it? What does `hex <- strsplit(gsub("(.{2})", "\\1 ", substr(txt, 3, nchar(txt))), " ", T)[[1]];raw <- as.raw(as.hexmode(hex));writeBin(raw, tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip"))` yield?

Comment: @lukeA Thats perfect. WOW! Thank you